# Internal Office Domain and External Server Domain Trusts

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, sql-server

I have a single office domain - internal with an external IP address. This server is our office active directory running windows server 2008r2. (AD : PPInternal)

With that, I have a private cloud stack hosted externally, with another active directory within its LAN. (AD : PPExternal)

I want to grant users access to our SQL server database (within the private cloud stack) using the clouds AD groups. But enable people within the PPInternal AD the ability to login using their PPExternal credentials. So auth will be like:

Computer - PPInternal (PPInternal\Name)

SQL mngmt Studio - IP of server + PPExternal Login (PPEXTERNAL\Name)

Does anyone know the best way to set up the domain trust to allow this authentication? I am a little bit stuck here.

thanks

Comment: I'm a little lost on what exactly you want the end result to be, but this should build your understanding on domain trusts: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730798.aspx

Comment: Given that both domains are under your control, you should probably go ahead and create a two-way transitive trust at the forest level.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit counterintuitive to most people, but think of it like this:

- The accessed service (the database engine) resides in a specific authentication realm, `PPInternal` - let's call this our *target realm*
- The accessing principal (the user identity) resides in a different authentication realm, `PPExternal` - let's call this our *client realm*

In order for the service to verify that the user can be trusted, and that the authorization information provided is trustworthy, it needs to trust the authentication authority in the *client realm*.

Since the service has trust in its own domain controllers (authenticators in the *target realm*), all you need to do is create a trust that satisfy this need; being able to trust the authenticity of principals from the client realm.

Instead of creating a two-way forest trust, you want to creat a one-way trust. If you only intend to provide this trust for the two domains in question, and not any other domains within their respective forest (future or pre-existing), I would suggest going for an **External trust**.

### In the *target realm* (`PPInternal`):

From **Active Directory Domains and Trust**, create a trust with these properties:

- Partner FQDN: `<FQDN of PPExternal>`
- Trust type: One-way External
- Direction: Outgoing
- Transitivity: Non-transitive

If you have credentials for a Domain Admin member account in PPExternal at hand already, choose to complete the trust before finishing the wizard.

If not, go to the *client realm* (`PPExternal`) and repeat the steps, but choose the opposite direction.

Congratulations, you've just created a trust relation between two foreign Active Directory domains :-)